# Choosing primary keys for "WHERE x > ?" query in CQL?

Tags: database, cassandra, key, primary-key

I have a table with columns `(a,b,c,d,e)`, where `(a,c,d)` are the minimum requirements for a unique value. I would like to query `SELECT * from {table} WHERE c>0`. As you cannot use `>` or `<` for the partition key, the only alternative I can think of is to let `a` or `d` be the primary key, and use `ALLOW FILTERING`.

Is this optimal, or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If at all possible you should try to narrow your queries so that they don't have to reference your entire data set. If you do need to, then using a batch analytics tool is the right solution if the query is not often executed. Remember Cassandra is designed for working with terabytes of data so a query which requires checking all of the data in the system should be a rare event.